# Vsftpd Implementation "Per-user only one active concurrent session is allowed"

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

Vsftpd Implementation "Per-user only one active concurrent session is allowed"

I found that Pure-FTP has this compile options "--with-peruserlimits". I wonder if vsftpd has this option?

Comment: You can't ask a question and go *"nevermind, it was for a challenge lol"*. This is an issue that can be experienced in the realworld that doesn't have a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no ([Source](https://linux.die.net/man/5/vsftpd.conf)).

I couldn't find anything mentioning limit by user on that man page, so i think we can't do that.

Comment: Never mind, this is a question from the 45th worldskills competition network system administration!  :)

Comment: Oh are they? So do you happen to have the answer? I kinda curious too

Comment: e. No answer! If you are interested, I can send you the topic, although the competition is over!
this is worldskills45 of cyber security issues, be not network system administrator! I remember it wrong
download address: www.worldskills.org